# spreading range of IPs to a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following code, what I am trying to do is create a small function so a when an IP range (contains : in it) is inputted all range is appended to the list.

```
collected_ips = []
while True:
    query = input("IP:\t")
    if not query:
        break
    elif len(query.split('.'))==4:
        temp = query.split('.')
        #result1 = all([i.isdigit() for i in t]) #must be True
        if query.find(":")==-1:
            try:
                result2 = all([0<=int(i)<=255 for i in temp])
                if result2:
                    collected_ips.append(query)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please Fix Input")
        elif len(x.split(":"))==2:
            #function here
            #append to collected_ips
        else:
            print("Please Fix Input")
    else:
        print("Please Fix Input")
```

example of input:

```
123.123.30.20:50
```

output:

```
['123.123.30.20,'123.123.30.21'...'123.123.30.50']
```

example of input:

```
123.123.20:50.30
```

output:

```
['123.123.20.30','123.123.21.30',...'123.123.50.30']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `range` to generate numbers between two ranges:

```
def spread_ip_range(ip):
    splits = ip.split('.')
    indx = next((i for i, x in enumerate(splits) if ':' in x), -1)

    lst = []

    if indx != -1:
        _from, to = splits[indx].split(':')
        ranges = range(max(0, int(_from)), min(255, int(to)) + 1))

        for r in ranges:
            s = '.'.join(splits[:indx]) + '.' + str(r)
            if splits[indx+1:]:
                s += '.' + '.'.join(splits[indx+1:])
            lst.append(s)
    return lst
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> spread_ip_range('123.123.20:50.30')
['123.123.20.30', '123.123.21.30', '123.123.22.30', ......, '123.123.49.30', '123.123.50.30']
```

-

```
>>> spread_ip_range('123.123.30.20:50')
['123.123.30.20', '123.123.30.21', '123.123.30.22', ......, '123.123.30.49', '123.123.30.50']
```

Comment: can you write this as a function so I approve answer?

Comment: Updated answer now.

Comment: can I directly append to `collected_ips` instead of 1st ?

Comment: Yes you can. They are just variables; does not matter.

Comment: Done, how can i make sure that range is between (0 and 255) in you function

Comment: Checking `_from` and `to` before doing `range` is one option.

Comment: If you haven't figured it out, I just updated mine. Now if the max range is 2500 (for ex), this will form ips only till 255.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this more concisely using reduce (from functools):

```
from functools import reduce
def expandIp(ip):
  nodes  = [list(map(int,n.split(":"))) for n in ip.split(".")]
  ranges = [range(max(n[0],0),min(n[-1]+1,256)) for n in nodes]
  ips    = reduce(lambda a,rng: [ip+[n] for ip in a for n in rng],ranges,[[]])
  return [".".join(str(n) for n in ip) for ip in ips]
```

- `nodes` converts the ip pattern into a list of range values [start] or [start,end]
- `ranges` converts the nodes into actual ranges using the start number as the end when there is not a ':' specifier for the node (also caps the node to range 0...255)
- `ips` combines each node range with all values of preceding nodes
- The result is the concatenation of nodes in each combination with a "." as separator

*note: this solution will work for multiple range specifiers in the ip parameter. e.g. `expandIp("10.1.1:2.100:101")` will produce: 10.1.1.100, 10.1.1.101, 10.1.2.100, 10.1.2.101.  So if you intend to use it for subnets, you will be able to do `expandIp("10.0.1:3.0:255")`*

By the way, you could validate the `ip` parameter with a single condition at the beginning of the function or before calling it (then you wouldn't need to use min/max to assign the `ranges` variable):

```
n0255 = { str(n) for n in range(256) }  
if not all( i<4 and j<2 and r in n0255 for i,n in enumerate(ip.split(".")) for j,r in enumerate(n.split(":"))):
    print("Invalid Input")
```

The final function would look like this:

```
from functools import reduce
n0255 = { str(n) for n in range(256) }  
def expandIp(ip):
  if not all( i<4 and j<2 and r in n0255 for i,n in enumerate(ip.split(".")) for j,r in enumerate(n.split(":"))):
      return None
  nodes  = [list(map(int,n.split(":"))) for n in ip.split(".")]
  ranges = [range(n[0],n[-1]+1) for n in nodes]
  ips    = reduce(lambda a,rng: [ip+[n] for ip in a for n in rng],ranges,[[]])
  return [".".join(str(n) for n in ip) for ip in ips]
```

which would simplify your calling code down to :

```
collected_ips = []
while True:
    query = input("IP:\t")
    if not query:
        break
    ips = expandIp(query)
    if not ips:
        print("Invalid Input")
    else:
        collected_ips += ips
```

Comment: how can I edit this so that any IP outside 0 to 255 isn't returned

Comment: Preprocess the ranges to set minimum and maximum values. I updated my answer.

Comment: nice,your if statement makes the code much more compact when verifying the input is valid